# How to bundle a nodejs server application and prepare it for distribution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, server

First of all, I'm not after a technique to package my application into a single executable.

I'm curious to find out what is the approach to create a copy of the app within the current project that is ready to be moved to server-enabled location.

Right now my server app is a git repo and it has all the usual files in there,  together with the source folder:

```
./src/server/index.js
```

Do we simply copy everything that is in the `./src/server` folder to `./dist/` then also copy the `package.json` into `./dist`?

Then we copy the contents of the `./dist` folder to a location that will be able to serve the application, like `/www/app2/` and inside that location, we make sure that we have `NODE_ENV=production` in the environment and run `npm install` to pull the production dependencies?

But then, our `package.json` file would still have the development related scripts and other things we don't need in production?

What is a best-practices way to deploy a NodeJs app?

--- UPDATE ---

This is what I have prototyped so far and it is working:

```
"scripts": {
        "clean:dist": "./node_modules/.bin/rimraf dist",
        "prep:dist": "./node_modules/.bin/mkdirp ./dist",
        "copy:server": "./node_modules/.bin/ycopy ./src/server/ ./dist/ -r '^((?!tests$).)*$' -i",
        "copy:package": "./node_modules/.bin/copyfiles package-production.json ./dist/",
        "build": "npm run clean:dist && npm run prep:dist && npm run copy:server",
        "start:dev": "nodemon src/server/index.js",
        "start:server": "node dist/server/index.js",
        "prompt": "echo 'No prompt functionality available'",
        "greet": "echo 'Welcome to my project.'"
    },
```

So the idea is to selectively move bits from the `dev/src` folder to a production ready `dist` folder. The idea behind having a simple package.json file is that we will not be needing the `dev` dependencies in there also we will not be needing most of the `dev scripts` as well. So probably something like the following will be enough:

```
"scripts": {
    "setup:server": "NODE_ENV='production' && npm install"
    "start:server": "pm2 start index.js"
}
```

... or maybe we would like to have some `csh/bash` scripts inside `./dist/bin` that will streamline the start process.

```
"scripts": {
    "start:server": "./bin/launcher"
}
```

I can definitely see a need for a custom project tree structure existing within the the `./dist` folder and totally different to the `./src` structure.

Comment: At the end of the day, when an OSX app is bundled, it will have a specific directory structure and things like `rpaths` will be tweaked as `dyso` files are copied and bundled into the final app package. I'm curious to know how people handle these situations when dealing with bundling nodejs server applications.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the "development" contents of your package.json are a problem, so perhaps I am not getting the crux of your problem.  However, for our environment we deploy all of our node apps (primarily microservices) with ansible.  The deployment package is just a tarball (could be a zip file).  The ansible package includes templates for a config.js file and a pm2 startup.json file that are both customized based on the environment of the target (staging/test vs production).

Let me know if you want a few more details if you are interested in this approach.

Comment: Thanks. I'm adding some more info to the end of my questions.